# d3 javascript, get distance between two points in an svg path

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, path, distance

I have a set of points through which I have drawn a path.

```
let path=svg.append("path").attr("id","path")
        .data([points])
        .attr("d", d3.line()
        .curve(d3.curveCatmullRom));
```

I now want to get the distance of the path between the points so that I can break it into segments. I have tried incrementing the distance and checking if the points (rounded off to 5) match with that of the initial set of points and thereby getting the distance whenever there is a match. I then save the points until there as a list.

Here, `xyArray` has the list of points to which I append `d` and the list `seg` as well.

```
function distanceBetween2Points(path, xyArray) {
    let distance = 0;
    xyArray.forEach(function(d,i)
    {
        let flag=1;
        seg=[];

        while(flag)
            {let pt=path.getPointAtLength(distance);
            if(round5(pt.x)==round5(d.x) && round5(pt.y)==round5(d.y))
                {console.log("d",i);
                d.d=distance;
                d.seg=seg;
                flag=0;
                break;}
            seg.push([pt.x,pt.y]);
            distance++;}
        return 0;
    });
}
```

It sometimes works (even though not accurately) but sometimes does not, depending on the data. Is there a better way to get the distance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a demo using vanilla javascript not d3 but I hope you'll find it useful.

The function `getLengthForPoint(p,thePath)`is calculating the distance on the path for a given point p. 
I'm setting a variable `let precision = 100;`. Depending on the length of the path you may want to change this value to something else.

Also keep in  mind that a path can pass through the same point multiple times. This can be tricky and can give you an error.

Also as you may know you will get the approximated distance to a point. In this example the point `p1 = {x:93.5,y:60}`. The point at the calculated length has this coords: `{x:93.94386291503906,y: 59.063079833984375}`

```js
// some points on the path
let p1 = {x:93.5,y:60}
let p2 = {x:165,y:106}
//the total length of the path
let pathLength = thePath.getTotalLength();
let precision = 100;
let division = pathLength / precision;

function getLengthForPoint(p,thePath){
    let theRecord = pathLength;
    let theSegment;
    for (let i = 0; i < precision; i++) {
    // get a point on the path for thia distance
    let _p = thePath.getPointAtLength(i * division);
    // get the distance between the new point _p and the point p
    let theDistance = dist(_p, p);
    if (theDistance < theRecord) {
    // if the distance is smaller than the record set the new record
      theRecord = theDistance; 
      theSegment = i;
    }
  }
  return(theSegment * division);
  }


let theDistanceOnThePath = getLengthForPoint(p1,thePath);

//if you calculate the coords of a point at the calculated distance you'll see that is very near the point 
console.log(thePath.getPointAtLength(theDistanceOnThePath));


let theDistanceBetween2PointsOnThePath = getLengthForPoint(p2,thePath) - getLengthForPoint(p1,thePath);





// a helper function to measure the distance between 2 points
function dist(p1, p2) {
  let dx = p2.x - p1.x;
  let dy = p2.y - p1.y;
  return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
}
```

```css
svg{border:solid}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 10 340 120">
<path id="thePath" fill="none" stroke="black" d="M10, 24Q10,24,40,67Q70,110,93.5,60Q117,10,123.5,76Q130,142,165,106Q200,70,235,106.5Q270,143, 320,24"></path>
  <circle cx="93.5" cy="60" r="2" fill="red"/>
  <circle cx="165" cy="106" r="2" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

To get the distance between 2 points on the path you can do:

```
let theDistanceBetween2PointsOnThePath = getLengthForPoint(p2,thePath) - getLengthForPoint(p1,thePath);
```